# List all the subdirectories of a chosen folder / bash script

Tags: bash, loops, sh, subdirectory

I have an issye with my script. I have to write a script which collects information about each subfolder in the folder given as an argument, including: the name of the subfolder and the number of files in it (`ls ... |wc -l`).
That's what I tried... But it doesn't search in one folder but in all of these.

```
#!/bin/bash
read $name

for i in $name/*;
do
        [ -d "$i" ] && echo ${i##*/} $(ls -l "$i" | wc -l);
done
```

Comment: If you write the loop as `for i in "$name"/*/`, you don't need the test for `[ -d ...]`, because you get only directories. I would however test for the existence of the directory `$name` itself.

Answer (score 2):

In general you [don't want to parse the output of ls in a script](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Perhaps try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read name
shopt -s nullglob
for i in "${name}"/* ; do
  if [[ -d "${i}" ]] ; then
    i_files=( "${i}"/* )
    echo "${i##*/}" "${#i_files[@]}"
  fi
done
```

This puts the list of files in each directory into an array, then prints the length of the array. `shopt -s nullglob` is necessary to ensure that the array is empty if there are no files inside the directory, otherwise the array will be length 1 and contain the unmatched glob in its unexpanded form.